# How can I create my own custom functions for Closure templates in Plovr

Tags: google-closure, plovr, google-closure-templates

I'm using [Plovr](http://www.plovr.com/) and would like to use my own custom function (specifically a [ucfirst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript/1026087#1026087) function) inside templates. At the moment I'm only interested in rendering the templates as javascript, and since this is a fairly simple case I think actually writing the code shouldn't be too much of an issue (using a Plovr-included [custom function](http://code.google.com/p/plovr/source/browse/src/org/plovr/soy/function/SubstringFunction.java)  as a starting point).

The question then becomes: how do I build it and use it with Plovr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should look at the [soy-function-plugins](http://plovr.com/options.html#soy-function-plugins) plovr option, if you have not already.

As shown in the example, you need to create a Guice module that loads the classes for your custom functions (such as [PlovrModule.java](https://code.google.com/p/plovr/source/browse/src/org/plovr/soy/function/PlovrModule.java)). The example from the options page works without any extra work because `org.plovr.soy.function.PlovrModule` is already in `plovr.jar`, so it is already on the classpath when you run plovr. If your `AbstractModule`/`SoyJsSrcFunction` is compiled into another jar, such as `my-soy.jar`, then you also need to be sure to include it on the classpath when running plovr:

```
java -classpath my-soy.jar:plovr.jar org.plovr.cli.Main path/to/config.js OPTIONS
```

[soy-function-plugins](http://plovr.com/options.html#soy-function-plugins) was introduced in the [February 2011 plovr release](http://groups.google.com/group/plovr/browse_thread/thread/601d505aa935c619).